# Method Not Allowed Error 405 Facebook App

Tags: javascript, facebook

I followed this tutorial http://www.9lessons.info/2012/07/facebook-invite-friends-api.html to make my facebook app My test website connected to this app is http://wowvi.blogspot.ro/ but i get "Method Not Allowed  Error 405" on my app page https://apps.facebook.com/wowvideos/ What am i doing wrong?

```
    <script src="connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>;
    <script>
    FB.init({
        appId:'282958875171257', cookie:true, status:true, xfbml:true }); 
    function FacebookInviteFriends() {
             FB.ui({
                method: 'apprequests', message: 'Your Message Here' });
        } 
    </script> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div> <span class="invite-friends-link"><a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> Invite Friends Link Text </a></span> 
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
       if (top.location!= self.location) {
            top.location = self.location }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please show your code you have implemented

Comment: '<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId:'282958875171257',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});
function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message Here'
});
}
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<span class="invite-friends-link"><a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();">
Invite Friends Link Text
</a></span>
<script type='text/javascript'>
if (top.location!= self.location)
{
top.location = self.location
}
</script>'

Comment: everything works well with the invites, but when i click on the invite notification , it takes me to my app https://apps.facebook.com/wowvideos/ and i get the 405 error

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flask facebook canvas app - 405 method not allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802692/flask-facebook-canvas-app-405-method-not-allowed)